Problem with implementing the Wikipedia (Tic Tac Toe#Strategy)

Quote from Wikipedia (Tic Tac Toe#Strategy)
A player can play a perfect game of Tic-tac-toe (to win or, at least, draw) if they choose the first available move from the following list, each turn, as used in Newell and Simon's 1972 tic-tac-toe program.[6]

Win: If you have two in a row, play the third to get three in a row.

Block: If the opponent has two in a row, play the third to block them.

Fork: Create an opportunity where you can win in two ways.

Block Opponent's Fork:
Option 1: Create two in a row to force the opponent into defending, as long as it doesn't result in them creating a fork or winning. For example, if "X" has a corner, "O" has the center, and "X" has the opposite corner as well, "O" must not play a corner in order to win. (Playing a corner in this scenario creates a fork for "X" to win.)
Option 2: If there is a configuration where the opponent can fork, block that fork.

Center: Play the center.

Opposite Corner: If the opponent is in the corner, play the opposite corner.

Empty Corner: Play an empty corner.

Empty Side: Play an empty side.



I have a problem correctly implementing the 4th step in the algorithm which is to block the opponent fork which is  in my code represented in the select_blocking_fork_move .
This is example when my player play against himself :
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . X . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   

   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . X . . O
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   

   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . X . . O
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . X . . .
   
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . X . . O
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . X . . O

// Here O should not played the right bottom corner , but he should have blocked X fork by playing right to X in the center . 

   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . X X . O
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . X . . O

   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . O X X . O
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . X . . O

   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . O X X X O
   . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . .
   . . . X . . O

X won !

This is the full code of my player :
#include "the_player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

THE_PLAYER::THE_PLAYER(const std::string& name) : _name(name), _mark(Mark::None), _opponent_mark(Mark::None) {}

std::string THE_PLAYER::get_name() const {
    return _name;
}

Mark THE_PLAYER::get_mark() const {
    return _mark;
}

void THE_PLAYER::assign_mark(Mark player_mark) {
    _mark = player_mark;
    _opponent_mark = (_mark == Mark::Cross) ? Mark::Zero : Mark::Cross;
}

void THE_PLAYER::notify(const GameView& view, const Event& event) {
    // Implement if needed
}

bool THE_PLAYER::is_valid_move(const GameView& game, const Point& move) const {
    const auto& field = game.get_state().field;
    return field->get_value(move) == Mark::None;
}

bool THE_PLAYER::is_winning_move(const GameView& game, const Point& move, Mark mark) const {
    const auto& field = game.get_state().field;
    const auto& settings = game.get_settings();
    int win_length = settings.win_length;

    const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> directions = { {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1} };
    for (const auto& dir : directions) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < win_length; ++i) {
            Point p = { move.x + i * dir.first, move.y + i * dir.second };
            if (!settings.field_size.is_within(p) || field->get_value(p) != mark) break;
            ++count;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < win_length; ++i) {
            Point p = { move.x - i * dir.first, move.y - i * dir.second };
            if (!settings.field_size.is_within(p) || field->get_value(p) != mark) break;
            ++count;
        }
        if (count >= win_length) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

std::vector<Point> THE_PLAYER::get_empty_cells(const GameView& game) const {
    std::vector<Point> empty_cells;
    const auto& field = game.get_state().field;
    const auto& boundary = field->get_current_boundary();

    for (int y = boundary.min.y; y <= boundary.max.y; ++y) {
        for (int x = boundary.min.x; x <= boundary.max.x; ++x) {
            Point p = { x, y };
            if (field->get_value(p) == Mark::None) {
                empty_cells.push_back(p);
            }
        }
    }
    return empty_cells;
}

Point THE_PLAYER::get_best_move(const GameView& game) const {
    const auto& field = game.get_state().field;
    auto empty_cells = get_empty_cells(game);

    // Win
    for (const auto& move : empty_cells) {
        if (is_winning_move(game, move, _mark)) {
            return move;
        }
    }

    // Block
    for (const auto& move : empty_cells) {
        if (is_winning_move(game, move, _opponent_mark)) {
            return move;
        }
    }

    // Fork
    for (const auto& move : empty_cells) {
        if (creates_fork(game, move, _mark)) {
            return move;
        }
    }

    // Block opponent's fork using select_blocking_fork_move
    Point blocking_fork_move = select_blocking_fork_move(game);
    if (blocking_fork_move.x != -1 && blocking_fork_move.y != -1) {
        return blocking_fork_move;
    }

    // Center
    Point center = { (field->get_current_boundary().min.x + field->get_current_boundary().max.x) / 2,
                     (field->get_current_boundary().min.y + field->get_current_boundary().max.y) / 2 };
    if (is_valid_move(game, center)) {
        return center;
    }

    // Opposite Corner
    for (const auto& move : empty_cells) {
        if (is_opposite_corner(game, move)) {
            return move;
        }
    }

    // Empty Corner or Empty Side
    for (const auto& move : empty_cells) {
        if (is_empty_corner(game, move) || is_empty_side(game, move)) {
            return move;
        }
    }

    // Random move
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, empty_cells.size() - 1);
    return empty_cells[dis(gen)];
}

bool THE_PLAYER::creates_fork(const GameView& game, const Point& move, Mark mark) const {
    const auto& field = game.get_state().field;
    const auto& settings = game.get_settings();
    int win_length = settings.win_length;
    int fork_count = 0;

    // Temporarily make the move
    field->set_value(move, mark);

    // Check for potential wins in all directions
    const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> directions = { {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1} };

    for (const auto& dir : directions) {
        int potential_wins = 0;

        for (int i = -win_length + 1; i < win_length; ++i) {
            int count = 0;
            int empty_count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < win_length; ++j) {
                Point p = { move.x + (i + j) * dir.first, move.y + (i + j) * dir.second };

                if (!settings.field_size.is_within(p)) break;

                Mark cell_mark = field->get_value(p);

                if (cell_mark == mark) {
                    count++;
                }
                else if (cell_mark == Mark::None) {
                    empty_count++;
                }
                else {
                    break; // Opponent's mark found, not a potential win
                }
            }

            if (count == win_length - 1 && empty_count == 1) {
                potential_wins++;
            }

            if (potential_wins > 1) {
                fork_count++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (fork_count >= 2) {
            // Revert the move and return true if a fork is found
            field->set_value(move, Mark::None);
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Revert the move
    field->set_value(move, Mark::None);

    return false;
}

Point THE_PLAYER::select_blocking_fork_move(const GameView& game) const {
    const auto& field = game.get_state().field;
    auto empty_cells = get_empty_cells(game);
    std::vector<Point> possible_moves;

    // Find all possible opponent forks
    for (const auto& move : empty_cells) {
        if (creates_fork(game, move, _opponent_mark)) {
            possible_moves.push_back(move);
        }
    }

    if (possible_moves.empty()) {
        return { -1, -1 }; // No forks to block
    }

    // Evaluate each possible move to block the forks
    for (const auto& move : possible_moves) {
        // Simulate the blocking move directly on the field
        field->set_value(move, _mark);

        // Check if the opponent has a winning move after this
        Point opponent_move = get_best_move(game);
        if (is_winning_move(game, opponent_move, _opponent_mark)) {
            field->set_value(opponent_move, _opponent_mark);

            // If the opponent's move doesn't create a fork, return this move
            if (!creates_fork(game, opponent_move, _opponent_mark)) {
                field->set_value(move, Mark::None); // Revert the move
                field->set_value(opponent_move, Mark::None); // Revert opponent's move
                return move;
            }

            // Revert the opponent's simulated move
            field->set_value(opponent_move, Mark::None);
        }
        else {
            // If the opponent doesn't have a winning move, return this move
            field->set_value(move, Mark::None); // Revert the move
            return move;
        }

        // Revert the simulated move
        field->set_value(move, Mark::None);
    }

    // If no suitable blocking move found, return the first valid move
    return possible_moves.front();
}



bool THE_PLAYER::is_opposite_corner(const GameView& game, const Point& move) const {
    const auto& settings = game.get_settings();
    int max_x = settings.field_size.max.x;
    int max_y = settings.field_size.max.y;

    return (move.x == 0 && move.y == 0) || (move.x == max_x && move.y == max_y) ||
        (move.x == 0 && move.y == max_y) || (move.x == max_x && move.y == 0);
}

bool THE_PLAYER::is_empty_corner(const GameView& game, const Point& move) const {
    const auto& settings = game.get_settings();
    int max_x = settings.field_size.max.x;
    int max_y = settings.field_size.max.y;

    return ((move.x == 0 && move.y == 0) || (move.x == 0 && move.y == max_y) ||
        (move.x == max_x && move.y == 0) || (move.x == max_x && move.y == max_y));
}

bool THE_PLAYER::is_empty_side(const GameView& game, const Point& move) const {
    const auto& settings = game.get_settings();
    int max_x = settings.field_size.max.x;
    int max_y = settings.field_size.max.y;

    return ((move.x == 1 && move.y == 0) || (move.x == 0 && move.y == 1) ||
        (move.x == 1 && move.y == max_y) || (move.x == max_x && move.y == 1));
}

Point THE_PLAYER::play(const GameView& game) {
    return get_best_move(game);
}


The Wikipedia algorithm is only talking about a 3*3 tic-tac-toe game, for larger grids you'll need a different algorithm

@AlanBirtles you mean a board with a 3x3 grid?

Yes, that's what i mean

Your game isn't the original tic-tac-toe game https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe

An a grid bigger than 3x3 the starting player always wins (so extending Tic-tac-toe  to a grid bigger than 3x3 makes no sense)

Nitpick:  common coding guidelines use ALL CAPS for macros and constants, not class names.
